# PagerAdapter-Viewpager with async task in instantiateItem loads products on the last created page

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-viewpager

I have `pagerAdapter` to show images fastly by swiping in `viewpager`. I want to load `gridview` images below each `viewpager` item. To avoid load all `gridview` images while swiping fast, I use `OnTouchListener` for detecting touch event and load `async task`. The problem is that when I oepn viewpager, it creates 3 viewpager page (I limited it with `setOffscreenPageLimit`), left-current-right. I call async task and it loads all item to the gridview, but the `gridview` images are not shown the `current viewpager page` because it loads gridview images on the last created viewpager page.

How to add async task images to the current viewpager item? Is my logic wrong? Can you suggest something to achieve this? 
Thank you for your attention.

Here is instantiateItem:

```
@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) container.getContext()
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.detail, container, false);

mGridView = (ExpandableHeightGridView)view.findViewById(R.id.product);
mGridView.setExpanded(true);

scrollView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                int action = event.getActionMasked();
                switch (action) {

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    initialY = event.getY();
                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    float finalY = event.getY();
                    if (initialY < finalY | initialY > finalY) {
                        if(!asyncTaskCalled){
                            new GetAsyncProducts().execute();
                            asyncTaskCalled=true;
                        }
                    }

                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_OUTSIDE:
                    break;
            }
                return false;
            }
        });

}
```

Async process:

```
  @Override
    protected void onPreExecute(){
        GetProducts.productID = list_pk.get(viewPager.getCurrentItem()); 
        new GetProducts(); // This is service and gets products.
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(View result) {
        listproducts.addAll(GetProducts.list_products);
        imgAdapter = new ImageAdapter(); // GridView Adapter
        mGridView.setAdapter(imgAdapter);
        imgAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }
```

Comment: Could you provide code for the `GetAsyncProudcts` class, please? Also, just to clarify: you have 3 separate gridvews, one per page?

Comment: No, one GridView for one page (if user touchs all pages one by one). I add async task process. See edit pls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because you have a single `GetAsyncProducts` object which is blindly loading data *somewhere*.  It's not associated with a specific `GridView` so whichever `AsyncTask` finishes *last* will be the one that "wins" and updates the `GridView`.  Since the code is not provided, it's not clear how you are tracking the data.  My suggestion would be to kick off your `AsyncTask` and associate it with a specific page so it updates that specific page's data/`View`s.

You'll also want to make sure you are tracking the different `AsyncTask` object instances so you can cancel them if the page is quickly dismissed or if your `Activity`/`Fragment` goes to the pause state.  Otherwise your `AsyncTask`s could end up continuing to work unnecessarily or (worse yet) try to update `View`s after pause, causing a crash of your app.

Comment: Hi Larry. Sorry for the late answer. Your answer helps me thx a lot. I solved my problem with `viewHolder` that holds my views seperately so I update view which I want. I accept your answer because your answer was my guide.

Comment: Thank you and glad you were able to get it worked out!